# Can a cemetery be referred to as “historical”?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Assume a cemetery that is commonly known as the Anglican Cemetery. It is currently in use, but a number of graves date back 200 years. A book about some of the early graves is entitled “A guide to the Anglican Historical Cemetery”.

It seems to me that “historical” implies “no longer in existence” or “no longer in use” and therefore does not apply to this cemetery.

On the other hand, is “historical” redundant? Aren’t all cemeteries essentially historical?

Comment: Have you checked in some dictionaries to see if your hunch is true?  The merriam-webster. with the Cambridge and the Oxford dictionaries would give a good idea.

Comment: Well, as you say, if we think strictly black-and-white, then either all cemeteries are always historical, or exacly none ever is. And that right there is our answer: the term is not used to distinguish cemeteries from non-cemeteries; that's what the word "cemetery" already does. Rather, it's used to differentiate between different kinds of cemetery. Not to tell black from white, but to introduce a shade of gray. Now, maybe there's a better word for the job, but I think this one does fine. I can think of cemeteries that are historical, and of cemeteries that are not. It brings the point across.

Comment: When in Ireland, my wife and I visited Glasnevin Cemetery, which certainly merits the descriptor 'historic' (associated with fascinating / important aspects of history) – it even has its own museum. Highgate Cemetery in London is also famous.

Comment: Anything that's in the past ***is*** *historical* by definition. The title of the pamphlet seems fine since, first, it's a title, and, second, it's emphasizing the past of the cemetery. If it was trying to emphasize the *importance* of the cemetery, I would expect the word ***historic*** to be used instead. Then again, it's possible that the particular cemetery has that word in its actual complete name—and it's not being used as an adjective at all.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth And ***historied*** cemetaries have their own tales to tell.

Comment: I don't see a problem with a place which is still in use being referred to as "historical". You can watch plays in historical theatres, live in historical houses and drink, or even stay, in historical inns. I worked in an historical factory once (although the product we made wasn't what it had been built to produce).

Comment: @BoldBen Do you find the 'an' helpful before 'historical'? I always aspirate fully and use 'a', but I know that many prefer 'an' before 'historical', 'hotel' and a few other h-words that are usually aspirated.

Comment: There has to be some point in time or significance of use at which a cemetery or a house or a bicycle changes from being from old to being historic.  A cemetery opened last week is not historic unless someone of great historical significance is buried there.  US Customs has solved this problem for its jurisdiction:  If it is 100 or more years old, it is an antique.  Otherwise it is merely old.

Answer (score 2):

In the U.S., many states define various aspects of historic cemeteries:

[Oregon](https://www.oregonlaws.org/ors/97.772)

> Definition of “historic cemetery.” For purposes of ORS 97.772
>   (Definition of “historic cemetery”) to 97.784 (Executive secretary),
>   “historic cemetery” means any burial place that contains the remains
>   of one or more persons who died before February 14, 1909.

Dates of such designations vary.  Some cemeteries have historic sections, and thus my still be currently in use

Comment: This answer refers to "historic" not "historical". It's not unusual for "historic" and "historical" to get confused (they have slightly different meanings but both meanings can be applied to some things). But for it to be a valid answer, it should really address the difference between "historic" and "historical" in some way.